# Utilizing Foreach to generate a submenu

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two functions I'm working on that interact with each other and at this point I'm trying to fix the submenu portion of it.

My menu is generated using

```
public function CreateNavigation() {
            global $db;
            $query = <<<SQL
            SELECT id,name
            FROM pages
            WHERE enabled = :enabled
            AND main = :main
SQL;
            $resource = $db->sitedb->prepare( $query );
            $resource->execute( array (
            ':enabled'  =>  1,
            ':main'     =>  1,
            ));
                foreach($resource as $menu){
                    $this->parentid = $menu['id'];
                    echo "<li><a href='viewPage.php?id=".$menu['id']."'>".$menu['name']."</a>
                    ".self::GetSublinks()."</li>";
                }

    }
```

And then the GetSublinks takes over to determine the dropdown of the menu

```
    public function GetSublinks() {
        global $db;
        $query = <<<SQL
        SELECT id,name
        FROM pages
        WHERE parentid = :parentid
        AND enabled = :enabled
SQL;
        $resource = $db->sitedb->prepare( $query );
        $resource->execute( array (
        ':parentid' => $this->parentid,
        ':enabled'  => 1,
        ));
        $row_count = $resource->rowCount();
        if($row_count >= 1) {
            return "<ul>";
            foreach($resource as $row){
                return "<li><a href='viewpage.php?id=".$row['id'].">".$row['name']."</a></li>"
            }
            return "</ul>";
        }
    }
```

Now the main menu itself works great, Even the sublinks work great to a degree. They check to make sure and modify the main link to show it has children if it does, but where I run into the issue is within the children it will only show the last of the links, so I can't have more than one dropdown because of this.
I have also tried changing my foreach within the sublinks to

```
while($row = $resource->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

To no avail. My menu works fine without having the dropdown, but the dropdown would be nice to add in.

var_dump($resource) Results:

```
object(PDOStatement)#7 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(86) " SELECT id,name FROM pages WHERE parentid = :parentid AND enabled = :enabled" } object(PDOStatement)#7 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(86) " SELECT id,name FROM pages WHERE parentid = :parentid AND enabled = :enabled" }
```

var_dump($row) Results:

```
array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(10) "Create New" } array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["name"]=> string(14) "Delete Listing" }
```

Comment: Do you mean Inner sub drop down is shown for Last menu only?

Comment: use     while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { and modify your example, edit it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your code reaches to

```
return "<ul>";
```

it will exit the function and return `<ul>` so it wont even come to foreach loop so you need to concatenate  string and than return it

> [`return ¶`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call. return also ends the execution of an eval() statement or script file.

```
if($row_count >= 1) {
       $sub_menu = "<ul>";
       foreach($resource as $row){
            $sub_menu .= "<li><a href='viewpage.php?id=".$row['id'].">".$row['name']."</a></li>"
        }
         return $sub_menu ."</ul>";
  }
```

Comment: Still seems like there's an issue with the foreach. I have it set that way now and it's still exiting after one result is returned. (The last result that is)

Comment: what are you getting when you `var_dump($resource)` ?

Comment: Added var_dump resource and row to the main question at the bottom.

Comment: you should do `foreach($row as $a)` and `$a['id'].">".$a['name']` because  `$row` has array not `$resource`

Comment: So just to be sure. A foreach within the foreach I have at the moment?

Comment: no you dont need another foreach, ? what are you getting when you do what i told in last comment it should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77060/discussion-between-morgan-green-and-nullpoite).

Answer (score 3):

I think your string concatenation and returning value is wrong. It should be like :

```
    if($row_count >= 1) {
        $subMenu = "";
        $subMenu .= "<ul>";
        foreach($resource as $row){
            $subMenu .= "<li><a href='viewpage.php?id=".$row['id'].">".$row['name']."</a></li>"
        }
        $subMenu .= "</ul>";
        return $subMenu;
    }
```

You should keep concatenating and at the end only return submenu.

Comment: Unfortunately that still returns only one of the dropdowns that I've enabled; I'm looking to see if I might have a typo or if it's just the way I placed the function inside of the other.